# .net Connectivity to mainframe

Tags: .net, mainframe, connectivity

Can any one please suggest me the best approach to connect to mainframe from .net.

I have to develop an web application, in which i have to follow NIEM standards for data exchange between two end clients. the interface i have to develop will be on .net. i don't have any knowledge on mainframe, i have come across that there are ODBC connectivity/ MQ series. i'm afraid which approach to follow on as i have less knowledge on the mainframe system. any suggestion would be really helpfully to me.

any article , links or sample code will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You might want to give more detail about "connect to mainframe".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect to a DB2 database residing on a mainframe, DB2Connect is the way to go (I think it may be literally the *only* way to go).

If you need your .Net software to talk to software running on a mainframe, however, your life will be less happy, especially if you know nothing about mainframes and the person responsible for the mainframe software knows nothing about Windows.  I've been in this latter situation a few times, and the simplest, most aspirin-free way to deal with it is to set up a file-share location on the mainframe that is accessible both to the mainframe code and to the Windows network, and have both sides exchange data by writing to and reading from files located there (yes, this is a hack, but one which works quite well).

Comment: can i follow the NIEM standards for the above file sharing approach ? dose mainframe provides the facility of providing the xml data files?  if so can you please provide me some article, link, code sample if you have. as you have worked on it you would be knowing in and out of it. please suggest!

Comment: is there any advantage of using linq in the project?

Comment: @vinod: sorry, I have no knowledge at all of the mainframe side of things - it's a totally alien world to me. In the systems where my .Net code had to interact with a mainframe programmer's code, we just informally worked out a convention for file names and a simple tab-delimited text file format. It sounds like you mainly need help on the mainframe side; sorry I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

More detail would be good.

- are you talking TCP/IP - which is possible but probably a PITA?
- are you talking direct database (e.g. DB2) interactions (see other answer)?
- are you talking about something more complex such as use of the WebSphere MQ mechanisms (which offer general data connectivity abstractions across multiple platforms/languages)?

Comment: I have to develop an web application, in which i have to follow NIEM standards for data exchange between two end clients. the interface i have to develop will be on .net, any suggestion would be really helpfully to me.

Comment: You might want to explain "PITA" to him, although I agree completely. :)

Answer (score 0):

Really need more information to provide a good answer.  But you can use ODBC or DB2connect for database access.

If you need XML for the NIEM data exchange you can use xml4c, xml4j or IBM Cobol has built-in XML parsing.

To move XML files between the two, your mainframe will support NFS, raw TCP/IP sockets, ftp, JCA, http, MQ...pretty much all the options you have on other platforms.

What mainframe technologies are you hooking up to?  CICS? WebSphere? z/Linux? USS? TSO? Batch Jobs?  IMS/DC?  If you provide some more information, perhaps a better answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB2Connection cn = new DB2Connection("Database=TEST;UserID=db2admin;Password=password;Server=IS500");
DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP01", cn);
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Refer to this link to clarify your doubts:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4870/Connect-to-DB-from-Microsoft-NET